# How to filter my results so it shows the last four months of data - sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that gets the last 4 months worth of results from the below query but I'm unsure how to do this.

This is what I have done so far:

```
Declare @Number varchar(30) = '12'
Select
month = month(EndDate),
YEAR = YEAR(EndDate),
SUM(DownloadUnits) as downloads,
SUM(UploadUnits) as uploads,
number
from testTable
where number=@Number
GROUP BY MONTH(EndDate), Year(Enddate),number
```

How can I filter it out so that when I pass month parameter (I haven't created it yet) it filters out the results so it only shows the last four months? (I have hard coded the number parameter for testing)

Comment: What's in the month param? 4 in this case or a month number to deduct 4 from?

Comment: a month number to deduct 4 from. Put pretend its Janurary(1) I would need to pull back 12,11,10 so I need to use year as well as month

Comment: @user3884462: So what you gonna pass as a parameter. A date value? Because just passing the month will not enough!

Comment: I suggest changing @ Number varchar(30) to @ YearMonth char(7) and pass in values like '2014-01'.   It will give you much more flexibility.  Better yet, pass in numeric values for the year and month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to get whole months then you will need to get the first of the month 4 months ago.

You can get the first of the current month using:

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19000101', GETDATE()), '19000101');
```

Adapting this slightly will give you the first of the month 4 months ago:

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19000101', GETDATE()) - 4, '19000101');
```

Then you can just apply this filter to your query:

```
WHERE   EndDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19000101', GETDATE()) - 4, '19000101')
```

Or if you need to pass the number of months a parameter (it should be an INT not a varchar by the way):

```
WHERE   EndDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19000101', GETDATE()) - @Number, '19000101')
```

If you pass a date parameter, just replace `GETDATE()` with your parameter name.

Answer (score 1):

The last N months from now meet the condition

```
where EndDate >= dateadd(month, -@DEDUCT_MONTHS, cast(getdate() as DATE))
```

Removing the `cast` will enforce the current time as a constraint as opposed to midnight N months ago.

Comment: So if I put -4 instead of @Deduct_months this would give me the last four months worth of data

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @StartDate date
SET @StartDate=Dateadd(Month, Datediff(Month, 0, DATEADD(m, -6, getdate())), 0) 
--first day of the month, (current month-6 month)
```

The script above will return with the first day of the month - 6 month ago .
This solution is from stackoverflow somewhere, unfortunately I dont seem to find the original post.. :(

To understand how it works try to reverse-engineer as per follows:

```
DECLARE @StartDate1 date
SET @StartDate1= DATEADD(m, -6, getdate())
PRINT @Startdate1


DECLARE @StartDate2 int
SET @StartDate2= Datediff(Month, 0, DATEADD(m, -6, getdate()))
PRINT @Startdate2


DECLARE @StartDate3 date
SET @StartDate3=Dateadd(Month, 1369, 0)
PRINT @Startdate3
```