# sql- show only the last four month

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-view

my good reference has been 
[How to filter my results so it shows the last four months of data - sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25285571/how-to-filter-my-results-so-it-shows-the-last-four-months-of-data-sql)

So far I have

```
SELECT ItemCode, SUM(QuantityOrdered) AS Total_Quantity
FROM OrderDetail 
GROUP BY ItemCode
ORDER BY SUM(QuantityOrdered) DESC;
```

It shows

```
ItemCode  Total_Quantity 
PL         1200    
MA          975        
153         200
```

While PL's Orders are qty 200 on 9/23/2011 qty 200 on 2/3/2014 qty 200 on 12/6/2016 qty 200 1/21/2017

How can I filter it out to show only last four months result from today's month?

Can I do something on Query design or SQL code?

> Any idea on Syntax error on line `WHERE dbo_SO_SalesOrderHeader.OrderDate >= dateadd(month, -4, cast(getdate() AS DATE))`. Thank you so much!

```
SELECT dbo_SO_SalesOrderDetail.ItemCode, SUM(dbo_SO_SalesOrderDetail.QuantityOrdered) AS Total_Quantity, dbo_SO_SalesOrderHeader.OrderDate
FROM dbo_SO_SalesOrderDetail INNER 
JOIN dbo_SO_SalesOrderHeader ON dbo_SO_SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderNo = dbo_SO_SalesOrderHeader.SalesOrderNo
WHERE dbo_SO_SalesOrderHeader.OrderDate >= dateadd(month, -4, cast(getdate() AS DATE))
GROUP BY dbo_SO_SalesOrderDetail.ItemCode
ORDER BY SUM(dbo_SO_SalesOrderDetail.QuantityOrdered) DESC;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a where clause and compare the "DateField" to the current date.  So if your DateField is named OrderDate replace "DateField" with "OrderDate"

```
SELECT ItemCode, SUM(QuantityOrdered) AS Total_Quantity
FROM OrderDetail 
where DateField >= dateadd(month, -4, cast(getdate() as DATE)) 
GROUP BY ItemCode
ORDER BY SUM(QuantityOrdered) DESC;
```

I am guessing that your datefield is actually in the OrderHeader table and if so you will need to join the OrderHeader table.  Below is an example

```
SELECT ItemCode, SUM(QuantityOrdered) AS Total_Quantity
    FROM OrderDetail 
    JOIN OrderHeader on OrderHeader.Orderid=OrderDetail.OrderID
    WHERE OrderHeader.OrderDate >= dateadd(month, -4, cast(getdate() as DATE)) 
    GROUP BY ItemCode
    ORDER BY SUM(QuantityOrdered) DESC;
```

Comment: thank you! will try soon and upvote! :) thank you again

Comment: Thank you for the 'JOIN' idea. You are correct on it! I have edited my question if you don't mind take a second look on it. I'd highly appreciate your help!

Comment: Im having a missing operator error. sorry for the follow-up ;) Thank you again! will response asap

Comment: I believe cast is invalid in Access. This should work: `WHERE OrderHeader.OrderDate >= dateadd("m", -4, Date())`

Comment: Thank you so much @ChristopherD. Both Joel and you saved me!! Have a great day!